# ros2 on qnx # error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h

Tags: ros2, errors

while building ros2 on qnx, i am getting the below error:

````
/usr/include/python3.8/pyconfig.h:104:3: error: #error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
 # error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h

```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was trying to run ROS2 on QNX with SDP7.1. I followed the steps from this [link](https://ros2-qnx-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/galactic/build_from_source.html). When I tried to build it, I got an error as mentioned above and the build didnt go thru. Need to know what have I missed or is there any steps missed in the above link.